# Tab key not indenting in Python

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7

I recently upgraded to python2.7 and noticed that the tab key does not function appropriately in the shell. Instead, it appears to search through the underlying directory (the standard unix behavior).

If I change back over to python2.6, it works appropriately. Is there a way to add this functionality back to 2.7?

For example:

> if foo:
>     (tab here) print 'bar'  #desired behavior is that tab key adds indentation here

**Solution:**
This is a known issue with python2.7 on Mac OSX. I used the following workaround to correct it:

```
$ cat > $HOME/.pystartup
import readline
if 'libedit' in readline.__doc__:
   readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I ed-insert")
^D
$ export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pystartup
```

Comment: Moar details! E.g. OS (distro), how you installed it, how you start it, etc.

Comment: Try insert tabs this way: `<Ctrl+V>Tab`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known bug with python 2.7 on Mac OSX. More details (including a fix) can be found in [the bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue10472).

Comment: Perfect. Fix in the original bug report corrects the issue. http://bugs.python.org/issue9907